# WordPress backend gallery - run custom JavaScript code each time an image is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have made the following custom adjustments to the gallery editor by extending the default view with: `media.view.Settings.Gallery = media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({`

I need to run some javascript each time a new image is selected for the gallery. Is there a nice way to do this and receive details of the newly selected image? or just try with a jQuery `delegate` on click?

If I could figure out what code loaded the URL, Title, Caption, etc.. fields and if there was a way to extend that, perfect!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It is theory but I guess you could save the WP media metabox, remove it with [remove_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box), alter the `frame.on( 'select', function() {})` then add it again with [add_meta_box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media for the reference

Comment: @vard thanks for those links! That should do the trick :) Cheers